# Matching all words ending with s

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a program that write a regular expression to match all the words where last letter ends with 's' . However the problem that I am having is, it is matching only the first word, and then it stops. so if I enter the expression: 
"james is great with us"

I expect

```
 matchObj.group() : 'james'
 matchObj.group(1): 'is'
 matchObj.group(2): 'us'
```

However I get only `matchObj.group() :  'james'`

I believe the problem goes back to the way match function works, is there a fix around it ? here is my code

```
import re



matchObj = re.match(r'\w+s', expression, re.M|re.I)

print("matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group())
print("matchObj.group(1) : ", matchObj.group(1))
print("matchObj.group(2) : ", matchObj.group(2))
```

Comment: Why not just use the `.endswith()` function of strings? Split your string on whitespace, then test each word with `.endswith("s")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `re.findall` like so to match all the objects contained withing a string:

```
words = re.findall(r'\b\w+s\b', your_string)
```

Comment: so there is no way for match to find multiple words ?

Comment: This is for multiple words. What are you talking about?

Comment: This is the pythonic way.

Comment: Probably want to use a word boundary at the end if you're going the regex route.

Comment: @hwnd Word boundary is irrelevant because the interposed whitespace won't be matched.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi you used findall. I am looking to use the match function and find multiple words. is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Mozein If `your_string` is a string containing all the words, then this will work. You have been talking in a riddle, do you mean an array of words?

Comment: This really works like a charm, it returns a `list` of all words in the string ending with `s`. Very much what OP requested. To put it differently: why do you need the `match`?

Comment: using match function in regular expression to find all the words with s at the end. I do not know how is that riddles

Comment: Use `re.finditer` with the same arguments.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: You need word boundary as hwnd said. `re.findall(r'\w+s', "list sync posts")` output `lis` and `posts`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a list comprehension:

```
sentence = "james is great with us"
new = [word for word in sentence.split() if word[-1] == "s"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @A.J.'s list comprehension better than this solution, but for those that like functional programming:

```
sentence = 'james is great with us'
print filter(lambda s: s.endswith('s'), sentence.split())
#OUT: ['james', 'is', 'us']
```